# Variable after flexible array member

Tags: c

Is there a way to put a variable after a flexible array member?
e.g.

```c
struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y[];
    int z;
};
```

Comment: As far as I know it must be last. If you think about how it is implemented that makes perfect sense. How would you allocate space for it otherwise?

Comment: Not directly; provide some context so someone can answer with an alternative way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: The only way I can think of is adding a pretty specific set of inline functions to get and set parts of an array.

Comment: The answer is no. But if you explain why you wanted this, perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Im trying to format a hardware packet and it has a payload with a variable at the end

Comment: Generally speaking, the easiest way to deal with that is just use a flat buffer, and keep track of offsets/pointers separately.

Comment: Alright ill do that. I was just looking for an alternative to that with this question.

Answer (score 3):

No, as the definition of a flexible array member is that it's last.  Per C17 6.7.2.1 §18:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an
> incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member.